# Is there an alternative to Views (Drupal) for Bolt-CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

We like BOLT CMS as an alternative to Drupal. How can we create lists or tables in a similar way.

Comment: In a similar way as you would do in Drupal via Views.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no

Slightly longer:
The database model in Bolt is a lot smaller than Drupal's, so the querybuilder that is needed in Drupal is less necessary in Bolt.

Everything you see in the bolt frontend is done in your template, you can extend that by loading content through queries like the following

```
{# get all blog entries which have been published before last monday #}
{% setcontent myarticles = 'entries' where { status: 'published', datepublish: '< last monday' } %}
```

(more examples at https://docs.bolt.cm/content-fetching)

Or you can extend bolt by writing extensions that do more complicated queries.

This is one of the main reasons Bolt is suited for "medium sized websites" - you can't do a big thing like Organic Groups easy, but you can do the small things like a simple set of pages much faster.

Comment: thanks, I am looking for a solution to store user data (such as tracking data) to the sql database and then retrieve them and view them via a bolt website. So, it's not about pages or groups but about retrieving data.

Comment: Ah, data retrieval is what the code above does, it fetches the content from the database so you can use it in your template https://docs.bolt.cm/content-fetching - pages in bolt are a simple content type, but you can customize the content types to your own needs, so you could store userdata too.